# ERROR 23 (HY000) at line 171862: Out of resources when opening file '

Tags: windows, xampp, mariadb

I try to copy my (mysql Mariadb) Database from Linux to Windows 10. I am using  XAMPP Version 7.1.9.

When I try to import database.sql I get an error.
ERROR 23 (HY000) at line 171862: Out of resources when opening file '.\db_name\table_name#P#20181015#SP#20181015_17.MYD' (Errcode: 24 "Too many open files")

Original database has partitions.
and in linux is set
[root@ACOPS mariadb.service.d]# cat override.conf
open_files_limit = 100000.

Linux mariadb configuration is exported and imported into xampp (Windows). There is Mariadb also.
How to configure this "open files limit" on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set

open_files_limit=100000

in your my.ini

Comment: Thank you Vladislav Vaintroub. You´re answer was  correct. Now I can go to resolve next steps.

Comment: Happy to help. Maybe you can mark my answer as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers now

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, check that setting via `ulimit -n`

On Windows, use mysql and do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit';`

What is the setting for `table_open_cache`?  Let's see all your config settings.

Partitioning is a nearly useless feature.  I advise against having more than 50 partitions in any table.  Also, partitioning does not intrinsically provide any performance improvement; there are very few use cases where it does.

There <strike>may be a hard limit</strike> *used to be a MyISAM limit* of 2048 in Windows, but I have not found confirmation of such.

Comment: hi, thank you for your help..open_files_limit 6210,  @@table_open_cache 2000 –This is working system on Linux. 
But I would like to create "create Db" script on Windows for protecting pre production

Comment: No, there is no hard limit of 2048 on Windows. Historically, MyISAM exposed a limitation of 2048, but it removed back in 5.1, 10 years ago.